# Edit titles of `NSOutlineView` inline

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nsoutlineview

I have an `NSOutlineView` and want to be able to edit the title of the entries in that list.

The list seems to support this by default but then the error is thrown as soon as I hit enter:

```
Exception detected while handling key input.
-[NSProxy doesNotRecognizeSelector:controlTextDidEndEditing:] called!
```

I tried to implement this method in my delegate but it did not get called.

I am having [this problem](https://github.com/Perspx/PXSourceList/issues/40) with a [PXSourceList](https://github.com/Perspx/PXSourceList) but I think it is a general `NSOutlineView` issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a bug in PXSourceList and is now fixed in version 2.0.3:

https://github.com/Perspx/PXSourceList/releases/tag/2.0.3

Answer (score 0):

The fact that an NSProxy is responding to your delegate call tells you that your own delegate is not connected to the outline view's delegate.

Check your delegate is connected to the outline view and look at the following documentation regarding delegates.

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/qa/qa1551/_index.html

Comment: Your comment indicated that this was an NSOutlineView problem, not just the problem of PXSourceList. Clearly as your delegate wasn't being called, that indicates you didn't set it up properly. The documentation provided shows how to do that. I don't understand why this answer was down-voted. –  blackirishman 13 mins ago